# Finger's Constant

Tags: big-list, decimal-expansion, constants

A fingers'constant is defined as to have as first decimal :

$$1.2345...$$

I ask for the most emblematic example .

For example :

$$2-\prod_{k=1}^{\infty}\left(1-\frac{1}{\left(k+1\right)e^{k}}\right)$$

Or :

$$\frac{3}{10}-\sum_{n=1}^{31}\left(-1\right)^{n}\prod_{k=1}^{100}\left(1-\frac{e^{-n}}{\left(k+1\right)^{n}e^{k^{2}n}}\right)$$

are one of these .

There is a lot of trivial examples .

As Tyma Gaidash answered my question partially I add a constraint :

Following my examples Is there some other representation  for these kind of constant than the  Champernowne constant series?

Comment: I don't quite get the importance. Can you enlighten me? If you start with 12345/10000, add any number less than 1/10000 to it?

Comment: It seems pretty trivial that this set of Finger's Constants are isomorphic to [0,1) via the map $x \mapsto 1.2345 + 10^{-4} x$. Since there is no representation for [0,1), there is none for these numbers either.

Comment: Do you mean the [Champernowne constant series](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Champernowne_constant#series)?

Comment: @TymaGaidash Thanks I was aware of the well-know constant but not the series !